# Boolean aggreagte in MongoDB array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, boolean

I have a JSON document as shown below

```
[
{a: "v1",b: "v2",c: "v3",d: [{k1: true},{k2: true},{k3: false}]},
{a: "v1",b: "v2",c: "v7",d: [{k1: false},{k2: true},{k3: false}]},
{a: "v8",b: "v9",c: "v3",d: [{k1: false},{k2: true},{k3: true},{k4: false}]},
{a: "v5",b: "v2",c: "v10",d: [{k1: false},{k2: true},{k3: false}]}
]
```

I want to write query as shown below:

```
select d from the above docs
where a = v1
and b = v2
```

The expected result will be following two documents:

```
{a: "v1",b: "v2",c: "v3",d: [{k1: true},{k2: true},{k3: false}]},
{a: "v1",b: "v2",c: "v7",d: [{k1: false},{k2: true},{k3: false}]}
```

So far, its easy. The query below will give you the result:

```
db.audit.find({a:"v1", b:"v2"},{d:1,_id:0}).pretty()
```

Question -

Now the requirement is to do Boolean operation among the retrieved documents.
"OR" Boolean operation should be on the values of respective keys (k1, k2, k3, etc.) found in the sub-documents of array elements of "d" key.

Wherever a key is not present, assume it false.

Is there to do this in MongoDB?

Its easy to programatically by assigning d to variable and then compare, but I am trying to find if MongoDB can do it directly.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Auro

Answer (score 0):

in mongodb 3.6 you can do this

```
db.bool.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
               a:"v1", b:"v2"
            }
        },
        {
           $project:{
             d:{
              $map:{
                input:"$d",
                as:"do",
                in:{$arrayElemAt:[{$objectToArray:"$$do"},0]}
              }
             }
           }
        },
        {
          $unwind:"$d"
        },
        {
         $replaceRoot:{
          newRoot:"$d"
         }
        },
        {
          $group:{
            _id:"$k",res:{$addToSet:"$v"}
          }
        },
        {
         $project:{
          k:"$_id",
          v:{$or:"$res"},
          _id:0
         }
        },
        {
          $group:{
            _id:null,
            res:{$push:"$$ROOT"}
          }
        },
        {
        $project:{ _id:0,
         res:{$arrayToObject :"$res"}
        }
        }



    ]
);
```

Comment: But here we are missing the comparison against individual keys. The requirement is to compare respective keys from the filtered documents.

Comment: The expected answer should be:
{ "result" : [ { "k1" : true }, { "k2" : true }, { "k3" : false } ] }

Comment: Can you please explain your question?

Comment: You are saying if any key has true value then that documnt should be returned?

Comment: The output should be a single document. In this case it should be { "result" : [ { "k1" : true }, { "k2" : true }, { "k3" : false } ] }

Check closely - first we filter two documents from the four documents.
Then we need to do boolean comparison on the respective keys (k1 with k1, k2 with k2 and so on) for "d".

Comment: ohhk , I need two check first then I will update my answer

Comment: Hello @Aurobindo can u pls try this?